# Extending Exuberant Ctags for Bash

Tags: bash, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Exuberant Ctags supports only detecting functions in Bash:

```
% ctags --list-kinds=Sh
f functions
```

However, there are options:

> --langdef=name
>
> ```
>    Define a new language to be parsed with regular expressions.
> ```
>
> --regex-=/line_pattern/name_pattern/[flags]
>
> ```
>    Define regular expression for locating tags in specific language.
> ```
>
> --langmap=map(s)
>
> ```
>    Override default mapping of language to source file extension.
> ```

How to extend Ctags for other things that may appear in Bash, like global variables, local variables? Also, functions with hyphens aren't recognized, how to fix that?

Comment: You shouldn't be using function names with hyphens anyhow -- nothing in bash's documentation guarantees that they'll work (and in some versions of bash they only work with the non-portable `function`-keyword declaration syntax). Until their availability is covered in documentation, such availability could just be an accident of implementation, such that their availability in current releases doesn't mean they'll still be available in the future.

Comment: ...and, err, all variables are global in POSIX sh; it's *local* variables that are a bash extension.

Comment: [Then again, I come from the Clojure world, where our language's author/maintainer is very, very clear that if something isn't explicitly promised in the documentation, there's absolutely zero guarantee of future support. I haven't seen any explicit rulemaking from Chet on the topic, but prefer to be conservative in which behaviors it's safe to rely on].